# Need to validate entire JSON response in Jmeter using Response assertion

Tags: api, jmeter

I have received a response in the following format

{"ErrorCode":"406","Message":"Employee Name should not be empty and  should not be more than 30 characters"} and to validate the same, i have added a response assertion and given the response in response text but when i try to assert it gets failed[image]

Kindly suggest me the right way. Thanks

Comment: it can work, show your assertion definition

Comment: I have tried with it and found some behavior and just want to confirm if my understanding is correct. am expecting a failure condition so the error code is in 400 so the assertion is always failed on using JSON response assertion. On verifying the same assertion using response assertion i am validating the entire response and the result is shown in Red ,only if the ignore status option is ticked,the test is passed with the assertion. If a same JSON assertion is validated with response code of 200 the test gets passed as per the expectation.

Comment: Is it a behavior of validating the response based on 200 and 400.

Answer (score 2):

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) there is [JSON Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) which is the right way to deal with [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) responses using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) language.

String operations like equals and substring as well as regular expression operations like contains and matches can be fragile given JSON nature of the response.

1. To validate the "Error Code":

   - Assert JSON Path Exists: `$.ErrorCode`
   - Additionally assert value: check
   - Expected value: `406`

     [image: JMeter JSON Assertion 1]
2. To validate the "Message":

   - Assert JSON Path Exists: `$.Message`
   - Additionally assert value: check
   - Expected value: `Employee Name should not be empty and should not be more than 30 characters`

     [image: JMeter JSON Assertion 2]

---

If for some reason you got stuck on earlier JMeter version you can play the same trick using [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your check include a new line character at the beginning.

JMeter uses the value you input as is, without trimming, so your solution is:

Remove spaces before/after your string. You can also split to several smaller assertion to make sure no extra characters added.